# How do I export a modified prototype in a Node.js package?

Tags: node.js, prototype, export, package

I can export functions:

```
exports.foo = function() { return "bar"; };
```

And I can modify prototypes:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() { return "bar"; };
```

But the latter only works in the Node interpreter. When I modify prototypes inside a Node package and then `require` the package, Node ignores the prototype modification. It complains that `Object.foo` doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you need to put up a little more code. Are you returning `exports = Object.prototype.foo` etc?

Comment: The specifics aren't important. I want to add a foo function to all Objects, and have the package do this whenever I call `require("foo")`.

Comment: waitaminute, you want to modify the global Objects for everything? That sounds ... dangerous. As for how to make that happen, you can't do that with a require.

Comment: It's called monkeypatching and Smalltalk, Ruby, and Lisp allow this. It's not dangerous. I just want to add a `foo` method to Object. What's weird is Node.js allows monkeypatching (just try it), but seems to forget the modifications when the exact same code is imported from a package.

Comment: I know what monkeypatching is, and I'm not sure how often it's suitable to be done to the base Object prototype. But I'm very familiar with the concept. As for why you can't do it when you import from a package, it's because you're assigning that into a variable. Lemme build an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since what you want to do is monkeypatch `Object` let us consider what is being done. I'm going to use an example from the joyent github page of the node project, as that's rather canonical and presents a solid example for comparison, that we all agree "works correctly" (cos if it didn't ... well)

> https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http2.js#L22

```
var util = require('util');
var net = require('net');
var stream = require('stream');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var FreeList = require('freelist').FreeList;
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;
var assert = require('assert').ok;

var parsers = new FreeList('parsers', 1000, function() {
  var parser = new HTTPParser('request');

  parser.onMessageBegin = function() {
    parser.incoming = new IncomingMessage(parser.socket);
    parser.field = null;
    parser.value = null;
  };
```

What we see in this example is a bunch of required modules, that are assigned to variables. At no point are those married back onto the `Object` prototype. The only way I can see to do this is to have code in the calling body that does the requiring to loop through those and apply them to the Object therewithin.

In other words, the only way I can see to do what you want is to do what you want in the root of your app. Or do some sort of combine against the two objects you may want to merge, if that's the goal.

Otherwise, you're restricting your prototype enhancements to the specifically returned var, and not to the root object.

Comment: Thanks for giving an irrelevant code example. Let me restate this again: I want to add a function to `Object`, but do so in a package.

Comment: Ad my point was, you can't do it that way, and I explained why not by usin real code. I Also gave a way in my code to do so.